# Hover query - NAV bar CSS effecting DIV class

Tags: css, hover

The following CSS code creates a NAV bar with some sample boxes within a container.

I was having problems with the Hover staying on so with some advice from here I included the extra code (second block of code down)

```
   .dropdown>ul>li>a:hover {margin-bottom:20px;}
```

This extra code worked well

However it has had a side effect on my DIV **boxleft** in that in wont stay left - as I move the mouse across the NAV bar it moves with it......... I just want to keep DIV **boxleft** on the left hand side. Can you help? Many thanks.

```
  /* Navigation Style */ 
    .dropdown { position:relative; font-family: arial, sans-serif; width:100%; height:40px; border:1px solid #666666; font-size:14px; color:#ffffff; background:#333333; z-index:2; } 

    /* Basic List Styling (First/Base Level) */ 
    .dropdown ul {padding:0; margin:0; list-style: none;} 
    .dropdown ul li {float:left; position:relative;} 
    .dropdown ul li a { border-right:1px solid #666666; padding:12px 8px 12px 8px; display:block; text-decoration:none; color:#000; text-align:center; color:#fff;} 
    .dropdown>ul>li>a:hover {margin-bottom:20px;}
    .dropdown ul li a:hover {color:#ffffff; background:#232323;} 

    /* Second Level Drop Down Menu */ 
    .dropdown ul li ul {display: none;} 
    .dropdown ul li:hover ul { font-size:13px; display:block; position:absolute; top:41px; min-width:150px; left:0;} 
    .dropdown ul li:hover ul li a {display:block; background:#000; color:#ffffff; width:170px; } 
    .dropdown ul li:hover ul li a:hover {background:#666666; color:#ffffff;} 

    /* Third Level Drop Down Menu */ 
    .dropdown ul li:hover ul li ul {display: none;} 
    .dropdown ul li:hover ul li:hover ul { display:block; position:absolute; left:145px; top:0; } 

    #container {
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:yellow;
    width:1250px;
    padding 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border:1px solid #666666;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }


    .boxleft {
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    width:600px;
    border:1px solid #666666;
    z-index:1;
    }
```

**EDIT**

Fiddle here : - http://jsfiddle.net/LUzNm/

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle....depicting your problem!!

Comment: provide markup, better come up with a fiddle in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Please see fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/LUzNm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than address this band-aid fix, let's address the root problem!

To begin, you don't need that `margin-bottom: 20px` thing. That was never the cause of your initial problem. Rather, it was due to the fact that your `.dropdown` bar is `40px` in height, but your actual dropdowns are absolutely positioned at `41px` from the top. If the browser registers a mouse event while the mouse is over that 1px gap, the dropdown will close.

Now, it seems like you want that 41px so a `border: 1px solid #666666` on your `.dropdown` bar will appear. We can do that still, but we'll just be adding that border to your hover menu.

And finally, let's get some best practices going. Padding can be useful, but padding for this use case sucks. Its far easier and more accurate to instead use `line-height` to achieve the height and spacing in our `<a>` tags rather than padding, and it allows us to do away with the extra `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` declarations on your site title! By setting `line-height` to 40px, we immediately match the height of the `.dropdown` bar at all times (and if you're using something like LESS or SASS, it becomes a great variable to reuse).

With all that being said, here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2r5Mz/

One more thing that I would also recommend doing is moving the entire `.dropdown` container out of `#container`. The reason for this is `#container` has `overflow: hidden` set, which can mean chopping off your dropdown if the content isn't of sufficient height. Simply moving this `.dropdown` out of that div solves the issue.